# Link to Microsoft coding standard/ best practices documentation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, fxcop

can anyone post the link to the Microsoft development best practices and guidelines?

i have searched high and low for this and cant seem to find the resource i am looking for. In particular i am lookign for the development guidelines Microsoft published to outline best practice in .net development... it contained things like closing connections, naming conventions, exception handling...

i remember when i was defining a corporate SDLC a while back and doing FxCop work and setup i had a holey grail of .net development from Microsoft that FxCop checks for and enforces.

can someone please help me locate this once again?!?!?

Comment: thanks all, but it was specific to best practices by Microsoft, put out by Microsoft corporation and i remember it had a section on why try{} and catch{} block was bad and detailed that this would just eat/ hide the exception and re throwing an exception in a catch causes overhead and is bad practice... instead of try catch it pointed out the use of if conditions... i remember this section clearly as i focused on this with my team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) on MSDN

If you want something you can take with you, then I suggest [The Hardcover Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613).

Comment: it was a pdf or word file, not msdn links... i need something i can take offline.

Comment: @kacalapy - I added a link to the offline version.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a nice c# style guide from Phillips, you can find [here](http://www.tiobe.com/standards/gemrcsharpcs.pdf)

**EDIT:** A new one i just found [Application Architecture Guide v2](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/5/9/D599BE85-07EE-4B4D-85D2-FC1C3EDD63B9/Application%20Architecture%20Guide%20v2.pdf) and [C# Coding Style Guide](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/TechNotes/SharpDevelopCodingStyle03.pdf)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While we are on the subject, here is a link to a [C# Coding Standards document](http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/pages/CSharp-Coding-Standards-document.aspx) I find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a single place where you can go for best practice guidance on that broad a scale.

A good starting point for app development would be [.NET Framework Core Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/190bkk9s.aspx) and [.NET Framework Advanced Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29eafad8.aspx), but that does not cover coding standards such as naming conventions.

Exception handling is covered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx).